# knockoutjs "checked" binding not working correctly in Safari and IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js

I have built a pricing calculator for different document types that gives you a final price based on the number of pages, quality and quantity in your document.

The pricing is generated by a service and the data for each request is outputted as a JSON object which is than used on the calculator.

So far everything works well in Chrome or Firefox, but not in Safari or IE.  I have been able to narrow down that the issue is with the Quality radio buttons.

The issue is that the pricing in Safari for example, is always incorrect when you use the "Quality" radio buttons. It seems that the first click on the radio button is not firing and you always get the incorrect price.

I've set up an example on jsfiddle with instructions on how to repro the issue: 
https://jsfiddle.net/IntricatePixels/f21dtr8j/

The example of JSFiddle should have all the details but I'd be happy to provide more info here on this post if necessary.

```html
<div class="form-group document-quality">
    <label>Quality</label>
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <div class="field-container" data-bind="foreach:categoryOptions, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: { change: onSubmit }" id="documentQuality">
            <label class="btn btn-default document-quality-label" data-bind="css: { 'active': $parent.selectedCategoryValue() === value }"></label>
            <div class="radio-container">
                <label class="btn btn-default document-quality-label" data-bind="css: { 'active': $parent.selectedCategoryValue() === value }">
                    <input data-bind="attr: {value: value}, checked: $parent.selectedCategoryValue" id="uniqueQuestionName" name="uniqueQuestionName" type="radio">
                </label>
            </div>
            <label class="btn btn-default document-quality-label" data-bind="css: { 'active': $parent.selectedCategoryValue() === value }"><span data-bind="text: label"></span></label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="form-group quantity">
    <label>Quantity</label>
    <input data-bind="value: copies, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" id="numberofCopies" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Even in Firefox, the first click of a radiobutton fails to register. Solve this and I suspect the other issue will follow. Why does it take 2 clicks first time round?

Comment: Thx @spender that's what I'm unable to figure out atm actually and was hoping someone here at SE could help with. But I agree that the first click that's not firing seems to be the root of the problem.

Comment: Please include all code needed to reproduce the issue inside the question itself. However, glancing at the jsfiddle, you should really also narrow it down some more: a *lot* of the code is not relevant to the actual problem, and it makes answering your question a lot harder.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Jeroen.  I tried to narrow down the code as much as I could actually, but agree that could have been narrowed down some more to make it easier to debug and see the issue at hand right away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though the codes might seem confusing I would say thanks to you I've found some tricks to knockout that I didn't it can be done in that way (but I doubt I would use though :D).

But let's get back to the point, let's just say that you are tired of cleaning your code for now and you want to continue with this. The issue with this is with this one `event: { change: onSubmit }`. When the function was called, the value of `selectedCategoryValue` is not updated yet (**note**: I only tested this on **IE11**, I have not available macs to use for now). This code which assigns the value of `selectedCategoryValue` only took effect after the `onSubmit` function executed.

```
<input data-bind="attr: {value: value}, checked: $parent.selectedCategoryValue" id="uniqueQuestionName" name="uniqueQuestionName" type="radio">
```

I tried two ways that worked.

**First** is the brute way that i don't recommend because for some personal reason i don't like setTimeout.

Add setTimeout in the onSubmit function.

```
self.onSubmit = function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.response("<div class='priceLoading'>Loading</div>");
            var servURL = "https://prices.azurewebsites.net/price/ProductionUS/" + ko.utils.unwrapObservable(self.selectedCategoryValue) + "/" + ko.utils.unwrapObservable(self.pages()) + "/" + ko.utils.unwrapObservable(self.copies());
            $.get(servURL, function(response) {
                self.response(response.PriceFormatted);
            });
            console.log(servURL);
        }, 100)
    }
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o16jnzyn/).

**Second** is more knockouty way, utilizing the subscription of `selectedCategoryValue` so if the value of `selectedCategoryValue` changes, then call the onSubmit function.

Change the old subscribe callback of `selectedCategoryValue` to:

```
self.selectedCategoryValue.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        self.onSubmit();
    });
```

And remove change event that calls onSubmit:

```
<div class="field-container" data-bind="foreach:categoryOptions, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" id="documentQuality">
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sfjd68rp/2/).

And lastly, you should really upgrade your knockout library (if it's possible) so that you can utilize knockout's new cool features just like `textInput` to change your `value, valueUpdate` binding combo.

Comment: Thank you Adrian! I used the second solution and it worked pretty well.  Going to upgrade the library to latest like you suggested as well.

Comment: No problem! glad to help ;)